# Is there any extra query in JSP u have t write if u have created sequence in database and you have to connect it through JSP page.?

Tags: java, sql, jsp

Example: Suppose i have created auto generated ID in database. And now in JSP page i dont have to create an ID column for it because it will be auto generated.. But when im running the program its giving error. So after creating sequence is there any extra query i have to write in JSP to specify that my ID is auto generated.??

Comment: _"... But when im running the program its giving error ..."_ - What error?  If you tell us what the error is, someone here might be able to help you deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have

...

`ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,`

...

in this case you don't need specify anything in Java, (but in case you wanted to use sequence then you need)

In case like above you can send Java object to ORM or to JDBC (with proper insert query) and DB will generate ID automatically.

Good luck